# pagination for WPF Documentviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

Existing WPF application has a documentviewer to show different types of data ( Images/ WordFiles ).

I required to add pagination on this documentviewer. user can also type page number to go on any specific page.

I searched on google a lot but not got any useful information.

If can we extend documentviewer functionality.. how can we achieve the required.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the relevant parts of your code, and explain where your specific problem is.

Comment: Exisiting code is there... You can consider the below example to open word document in document viewer .. if I open large document I required Pagination for that.. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/csvstoviewwordinwpf-db347436

Answer (score 0):

This control should be used more likely used in your case:

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
           <Paragraph>
                 //your text here
            </Paragraph>         
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentPageViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Dragosh Stoica... there is a lot code written with FixedDocument variable and It will take a lot efforts to change the controler... It will be great if we can give pagination in documentviewer control itself... can we extend it's functionality ...?